# What could be wrong with my keypress event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress, base-url

I'm trying to make a weather app, and use the API from openweathermap, I copied the baseurl from the web like this but it's not currently working...

```
const api = {
    key:"03173bc8739f7fca249ae8d681b68955"
    baseurl:"https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys"
}
const searchbox=document.querySelector('.search-box');
searchbox.addEventListener('keypress', setQuery)

function setQuery(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode==13)
        //getResults(searchbox.value)
    console.log(searchbox.value)
}
```

So when I type in the search box, the console doesn't show anything...
This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="weather.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app-wrap">
        <header>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="search-box" placeholder="Search for a city...">
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="location">
                <div class="city">HCM City, Viet Nam</div>
                <div class="date">Friday 25 June 2021</div>
            </section>
            <div class="current">
                <div class="tempt">15<span>°C</span></div>
                <div class="weather">Sunny</div>
                <div class="high-low">13°C / 16°C</div> 
                
            </div>      
            
        </main>
    </div>  




    <script src="weather.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with the baseurl or something, can anybody tell me?

Comment: if you don't put quotes around the reference `.search-box` javascript thinks you are passing a variable like `.search-box = "something"` which of course doesn't make sense. `".search-box"` tells javascript to look for that string exactly.

Comment: yah i did correct it but the console still announces the mistake at the baseurl...

Comment: `const api = { key:"03173bc8739f7fca249ae8d681b68955", baseurl:"https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys"}` - you are missing the comma

Answer (score 1):

wrap the selector with " ";

```
const searchbox = document.querySelector(".search-box");
```

also correct your api obj:

```
const api = {
key: "03173bc8739f7fca249ae8d681b68955",
baseurl: "https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys"
```

}

Comment: yah i did correct it but the console still announces the mistake at the baseurl...

Comment: i edit the answer, you forgot to add a comma after the key's value.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add single quote in querySelector.

`const searchbox=document.querySelector('.search-box');` // Corrected

also you need to update the API object

```
const api = { 
   key:"03173bc8739f7fca249ae8d681b68955",
   baseurl:"https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys" 
}
```

Comment: yah i did correct it but the console still announces the mistake at the baseurl...